# Cómo fusionar dos observables, padre e hijo

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Objetivo: Obtener un sólo observable al que suscribirse. Evitar suscripciones anidadas (tengo algunos problemas para renderizar las imágenes onInit). Puede hacerse todo con algún operador de rxjs, pipearlo... ?
Problema:

1. Realizo petición a server que me devuelve una colección de objetos. Entre las propiedades
   de cada uno de los objetos el nombre de una imagen asociada
2. Con ese nombre(ent.imagen) realizo una nueva petición al server
   para que devuelva un URL.createObjectURL que uso como dirección en
   el src de un  tag img

   ```
   this.entradaService.indexByAutor(this.owner!).subscribe({

      next: (data: Entrada[]) => this.entradas = data,  //hasta aquí el punto 1
      complete: () => { //una vez que  tenemos las entradas hacemos el segundo fetch

         this.entradas.forEach(ent => {
             this.entradaService.getStaticSingularImage(ent.imagen).subscribe({

                next: (imagen_url: string) => {
                          ent.imagen_url = imagen_url
       //añado la respuesta del segundo fetch como propiedad a 
       //cada uno de los valores emitidos en el primer fetch

                },
                complete: () => {}
          })
       })
      }
     }
    )
   }
   ```

Comment: Considera hacer que el servicio NO te devuelva un observable primero que todo, me refiero a tu `entradaService` ya que segun lo que describes estas intentando directamente usar `URL.createObjectURL` el cual segun la documentacion es un metodo `sincronico instantaneo` por lo cual no estas requiriendo el uso de ninguna operacion asincrona, usar observables en este caso es complicar  mas y hacer mas pesado algo que es mucho mas sencillo de hecho, yo luego en vez de usar un `foreach` usaria un `map`  y transformaria todos tus datos de manera directa en una sola linea